# In MongoDB, how come searching for an email that does not exist, crashes my entire app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In my Node.js express app, I'm just setting up a user sign in, this is my first time going through this just kind of self teaching.

I have this function here,

```
var db     = require('mongojs').connect('localhost/busapp', ['users']),
    crypto = require('crypto');

exports.new = function(req, res) {

    function User(email, password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    var user = new User(req.body.user.email, req.body.user.password);
    console.log(user.email + user.password);

    db.users.find({'email':user.email}, function(err, userFound) {

        if (err) {
            console.log('We have an error :(');
        } else if (userFound === 'undefined') {
            console.log('We couldn\'t find the user ' + user.email);
            return;
        } else {
            console.log('We have fixed the error, hooorraayyy!! ' + userFound[0].email)
        } 
    });

}
```

But the console log appears as

```
We found the user! undefined
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong if anybody could shed some light on the situation that would be great, thanks!

Ok so I fixed it by changing my code to the above, but now I have a problem, if I try to search for an email that does not exist, it crashes my entire app with this error:

```
C:\Users\Gacnt\Desktop\Busapp\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:529
        throw err;
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Gacnt\Desktop\Busapp\routes\session.js:22:72
    at C:\Users\Gacnt\Desktop\Busapp\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\cursor.js:159:16
    at commandHandler (C:\Users\Gacnt\Desktop\Busapp\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\cursor.js:628
:16)
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gacnt\Desktop\Busapp\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1709:
18)
    at g (events.js:175:14)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
    at Server.Base._callHandler (C:\Users\Gacnt\Desktop\Busapp\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\con
nection\base.js:130:25)
    at C:\Users\Gacnt\Desktop\Busapp\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:522:20
    at MongoReply.parseBody (C:\Users\Gacnt\Desktop\Busapp\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\respons
es\mongo_reply.js:132:5)
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gacnt\Desktop\Busapp\node_modules\mongojs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\
server.js:481:22)
PS C:\Users\Gacnt\Desktop\Busapp>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with javascript driver for mongo, but it looks like your line with the query itself is wrong. As for me your user object is undefined , it doesn't have an email property. Mongo js driver tries to resolve the value of this property even before it actually passes the query to the mongo engine, this failes for non existing users so you have an exception. Try to add a check whether the user object is correct before querying the mongo.

Btw, from your code snippet its not clear where do you print the message 'we found a user! Undefined' please double check this
Hope this helps